# Koin 2.2.1 : I cannot use "by viewModel" in Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewmodel, koin

**Cannot use "by viewModel" from Activity**

I want to inject a ViewModel for an Activity, so I tried this. But it was failed, Android Studio cannot find reference of it.

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModel()
```

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, and gradle dependencies includes these libraries:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
def koin_version = '2.2.1'
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-fragment:$koin_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$koin_version"
```

**What I tried:**

The code below is working, but I want to use new default "SavedStateHandle" feature of Koin 2.2.0.

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by inject()
```

I found this code was already included, Android Studio cannot find it.

ActivityExt.kt:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModel(
        qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
        noinline state: BundleDefinition? = null,
        noinline owner: ViewModelOwnerDefinition = { from(this, this) },
        noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null,
): Lazy<T> {
    return lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        getViewModel(qualifier, state, owner, parameters)
    }
}
```

In Fragment, both `viewModel` and `sharedViewModel` works fine.

```
private val viewModel by viewModel<SearchViewModel>()
private val mainViewModel by sharedViewModel<MainViewModel>()
```

**Question:**
What is the best way to inject ViewModel in Activity with Koin 2.2.0+ version?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I added this manually, and it works fine.

```
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
```

Comment: Can't use it in unit Test class. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the koin-android dependency:

```
// Koin for the dependencies injections
def koin_version = "3.1.2"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core-ext:$koin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModel()
```

to

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
```

You are missing an `s` in `viewModels()`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? Existing answers, including that from the OP itself, mention needing to import a certain package instead.

Comment: It is not a KOIN function, it is an androidx function. import androidx.activity.viewModels